# What is the best way to show online followers, node.js/socket.io and Redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, socket.io

My app is built in PHP (served on nginx/php-fpm) and I use node/js with socket.io for users push notifications.  These are pushed using Redis pub/sub to interlink between PHP and node.js

The node.js app maintains an array of online userid's.  They get added when a user connects to socket.io and removed from the array when they disconnect.

MySQL is used as the main database and I have a standard relationship table which denotes who is following who.  A list of followers userid's is retrieved when a user logs and displayed to them.

I now wish to intersect these two sets of data to provide live online status's of these relationships in a similar manner to facebook (a green light for online and grey for offline)

What would be the most performant and most scale-able way of managing this.  My current thought process is along these lines:

On the client side we have a javascript array of followers user id's.  Set up a timer client side which pushes this array to the node.js app every 60 seconds or so.  Node.js handles inersecting the followers id's with its current array of online users and returns an object depicting which users are online.

Now this would work but it feels like it might be a heavy load on node.js to be consistently looping through users followers lists for every online user.  Or perhaps I am wrong and this would be relatively trivial considering the main application itself is served by PHP and not via node which only currently handles notification pushing?

Regardless, is there a better way?  It's worth noting that I also use redis to build users activity streams (The data is stored in MySQL and redis maintains lists of activity id's)

So seeing as I already have a Redis server active, would there be a better method leveraging Redis itself instead?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: would a push from node to client work instead?

Answer (score 0):

If i remember right, when socket.io connected to client side, that makes a request to the client every time for checking active connection and return result, in callback succeffull you can put code that will be update time active users in DB. And when get last notes beyond 5 minutes from DB.